# Fetching data with an extra flag field based on table relation in Laravel (ORM)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

Say I have a master table called **category** like this:-

```
|-----------------|
|  id  |   name   |
|-----------------|
|   1  |   Egg    |
|-----------------|
|   2  |   Meat   |
|-----------------|
|   3  |   Fish   |
|-----------------|
```

And **user_category** table like this:-

```
|--------------------------------------|
|   id  |    user_id  |    category_id |
|--------------------------------------|
|   1   |       1     |         1      |
|--------------------------------------|
|   2   |       1     |         3      |
|--------------------------------------|
```

When I am fetching based on an user_id, I want to show the data in a fashion like this:-

```
|----------------------------------|
|  id  |   name   |   is_checked   |
|-----------------|----------------|
|   1  |   Egg    |       1        |
|-----------------|----------------|
|   2  |   Meat   |       0        |
|-----------------|----------------|
|   3  |   Fish   |       1        |
|-----------------|----------------|
```

This is because I want to create a panel where an user will see all the categories in a list with a checkmark besides the particular categories which he had saved.

I tried to do this like this:-

```
$categoryData = array();
$categoryList = Category::get();
foreach($categoryList as $cl)
{
   $category['id'] = $cl['id'];    
   $category['name'] = $cl['cname'];
   $isSaved = UserCategory::select('id')->where(
                                          array('user_id'=>$user_id, 'category_id' => $cl['id'])->count();
   if($isSaved > 0)
   {
     $category['saved'] = 1;
   } 
   else
   {
     $category['saved'] = 0;
   } 
   $categoryData[] = $category;
}
```

Is there any other way, like doing the whole thing by running one single mysql query instead of running the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the following code to solved the problem

```
$categoryData = Category::leftJoin('user_category', function($join) use ($user_id) {
                    $join->on('category.id', '=', 'user_category.category_id')
                         ->where('user_category.user_id','=',$user_id);
                 })
               ->select('category.id','category.name',
                                 DB::raw('
                                   (CASE 
                                     WHEN user_category.id is null THEN 0 
                                     ELSE 1 
                                    END) as saved'
                                 )
                      )
              ->get()
              ->toArray();
```